# Looking for a docker image with node, gettext and rsync

Tags: docker, deployment, gettext, dockerhub

For deploying a site via Bitbucket pipelines I am looking for a Docker image that has:

- envsubst (or gettext, I suppose to replace my environment secrets)
- node js (to build my web assets)
- rsync (to deliver my built assets)

Life is short, so before I go and read up on how to spec and host your own dockerfile, I tried to find a hosted one over at [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/). Turns out, I'm not very good at searching that thing. I get so many results and I'm not sure how to check if they have what I require. Does someone know of an image with at least these three elements? Or, how is a good way to search for one?

Thanks!

My bitbucket-pipelines.yml file:

```
image: andthensome/docker-node-rsync

pipelines:
  branches:
    staging:
      - step:
          name: Build and deploy to staging
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
            # fails here:
            - envsubst < .env.staging
            - cat .env.staging
            - npm install
            - npm run production
            - rsync -avz --delete public/compiled-assets/ root@redacted.org:/home/public/compiled-assets
            - ssh root@redacted.org 'bash -s' < devops/deploy_staging.sh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four months later and no answer, so I bit the bullet and built the docker image I needed: [janniet/build-pipe](https://hub.docker.com/r/janniet/build-pipe)

Now I can replace this hard-to-maintain deploy script:

```yaml
script:
    ...
    - sed -i "s|_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_|$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY|g" .env.staging
    - sed -i "s|_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_|$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID|g" .env.staging
    - sed -i "s|_DB_PASSWORD_|$DB_STAGING_PASSWORD|g" .env.staging
    - sed -i "s|_APP_KEY_|$APP_KEY|g" .env.staging
    ...
```

with this one:

```yaml
script:
    ...
    - envsubst < .env.staging > .env
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: I needed to replace environment variables in a file (envoy/envoyproxy config), and I solved it by

- having an init-container do the token replacement before my main containers run
- place the resulting file in a shared volume where the main container could pick it up

1. Make a simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.17
RUN apk add gettext libintl
```

2. Build the docker image in azure-pipelines:

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build and push envsubst image
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: '$(CONTAINER_REGISTRY)'
    repository: $(ENV_SUBST_IMAGE_NAME)
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    Dockerfile: deploy/base/envoy/Dockerfile
    tags: 1.0
```

3. Use the created image in your deployment (to run as an init-container for example):

```
     initContainers:
        - name: init-envsubst
          image: docker.container.registry/ensubst-image-name:v1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          command: [ 'sh', '-c', 'cat /etc/envoy-config.yaml | envsubst \$YOUR_SECRET_VARIABLE,\$ANOTHER_URL > /tmp/envoy.yaml' ]
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: secrets
                optional: false
            - configMapRef:
                name: environment-vars
                optional: false
          volumeMounts:
            - name: secrets-store
              mountPath: /mnt/secrets-store
              readOnly: true
            - name: envoy-config
              readOnly: true
              mountPath: /etc/envoy-config.yaml
              subPath: envoy-config.yaml
            - name: cache-volume  
              mountPath: /tmp
```

All these steps might be a bit more than what you need, especially if you're not using kubernetes; I wonder if in your case you could simply do:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    staging:
      - step:
          name: Build and deploy to staging
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
            - apk add gettext libintl # <--- this
            - envsubst < .env.staging
            - cat .env.staging
            - npm install
```